# Is there any parameter to remove the time stamp from 'date_input()' on streamlit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, streamlit

Is there any parameter to format the date when using `st.date_input()` in streamlit? I want to remove `T00:00:00`. This is the output:

[image]

I have written this code that allows the user to add new data to a DF:

```
st.sidebar.header("Afegeix una classe")

options_form2 = st.sidebar.form("options_form2")

dataClasse = options_form2.date_input("Data de la classe")

genere = options_form2.selectbox(
    "Gènere",
    ('H', 'D')
)
idCode = options_form2.selectbox(
    "ID",
    ('ABSUDUHM', 'DWHWBMMX', 'MIXEECJR', 'NFKQWKOP', 'RQWLPVCJ')
)
duradaClasse = options_form2.selectbox(
    "Durada de la classe",
    ('1h', '1h 30min', '2h')
)
preu = options_form2.number_input("Preu")

submitButton = options_form2.form_submit_button()

if submitButton:
    st.write(dataClasse, genere, idCode, duradaClasse)
    newData = {
        "Data de la classe": dataClasse,
        "Genere": genere,
        "ID": idCode,
        "Durada de la classe": duradaClasse,
        "Preu": preu
    }
    # Add new data to the data frame
    df = df.append(newData, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_excel("classes_particulars.xlsx", index=False)
```

However, the date format added to the DF contains the time, and I don't want it. I just want to add the date.
I have tried with `from datetime import date` but I am not sure how to implement it the right way.

Comment: Have a look in the official streamlit documentation of what [date_input](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.date_input) is.

Comment: I have looked into it to do the code but I have not been able to format it the way I wanted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a parameter but want you can do is to format your column.

**before:**

[image]

**Example:**
***Note:*** If the name of your column is not `Date` make sure you replace my `Date` index with the name of your column.

```py
import datetime
import streamlit as st


df["Date"] = [
        datetime.datetime.strptime(
            str(target_date).split(" ")[0], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        for target_date in df["Date"]
    ]

st.dataframe(df)
```

**After:**

[image]

**Edition:**

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import datetime


st.sidebar.header("Afegeix una classe")

options_form2 = st.sidebar.form("options_form2")

dataClasse = options_form2.date_input("Data de la classe")

genere = options_form2.selectbox("Gènere", ('H', 'D'))
idCode = options_form2.selectbox(
    "ID", ('ABSUDUHM', 'DWHWBMMX', 'MIXEECJR', 'NFKQWKOP', 'RQWLPVCJ'))
duradaClasse = options_form2.selectbox("Durada de la classe",
                                       ('1h', '1h 30min', '2h'))
preu = options_form2.number_input("Preu")

submitButton = options_form2.form_submit_button()

df = pd.DataFrame([])

if submitButton:
    st.write(dataClasse, genere, idCode, duradaClasse)
    newData = {
        "Data de la classe": dataClasse,
        "Genere": genere,
        "ID": idCode,
        "Durada de la classe": duradaClasse,
        "Preu": preu
    }
    # Add new data to the data frame
    df = df.append(newData, ignore_index=True)

    df["Data de la classe"] = [
        datetime.datetime.strptime(str(target_date).split(" ")[0],
                                  '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        for target_date in df["Data de la classe"]
    ]

    df.to_excel("classes_particulars.xlsx", index=False)

    st.dataframe(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried and it works but I will update the code as I want to implement this in a different way.

Comment: Please provide code and not screenshot and clearly explain your stack. Where are you reading the `date_input`?

Comment: You are right. I haven't explained it as I should. Now, I think I have explained at its best the problem I want to solve.
I have looked at streamlit date_input documentation but I still can't figure it out

Comment: I edited my answer with the version of your code, and you can refer to it and give it a try.